# Modify HTML tag from dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, gatsby

I am building a Gatsby Blog using React/Gatsby & the Wordpress API.

I render an excerpt of the latest articles on the landing page like so:

```
<span
  className="mb-0"
  id="excerpt-wrapper"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.post.node.excerpt}
/>
```

The problem is, my `this.props.post.node.excerpt` comes with an unwanted wrapping `<p>` tag. This tag inherit from Bootstrap CSS as I am using Bootstrap 4 in my whole project, and from the user agent stylesheet.

Hence I need to find a way either to :

- get rid of the wrapping p tag
- modify the CSS once the excerpt is mounted

I tried the following solution:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.removePTagMargin();
}

removePTagMargin = () => {
  const excerptWrapper = document.querySelector("#excerpt-wrapper");
  excerptWrapper.firstChild.style.marginBottom = "0px !important"
  excerptWrapper.firstChild.style.marginBlockEnd = "0px !important"
}
```

but it does not work (maybe because it executes before the WP API call is done ?).

How can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming the excerpt comes from `gatsby-transformer-remark`.

You can choose the format of your excerpt in your GraphQL query for the post, it looks like the format you're using is `HTML`, you want `PLAIN`:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/#format

Try modifying your query by putting the `format` parameter on the `excerpt` field:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        excerpt(format: PLAIN)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Hacky way of removing the `<p>` tags due to the inefficiencies in this `gatsby-source-wordpress` plugin.

Add a helper called `removeParagraphTags` this will simply trim the first three chars from the string and the last 4 chars from the string.

```
removeParagraphTags (excerpt) {
  return excerpt.substr(3, excerpt.length - 7)
}
```

Then you can use this helper when setting the excerpt HTML.

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: this.removeParagraphTags(this.props.post.node.excerpt)
}}
```

Comment: Hi @MichaelCurry, Thank you for your help ! unfortunately, the excerpt come from `gatsby-source-wordpress` and not `gatsby-transformer-remark`. Hence I can't use this option :(

Comment: @JulesCorb Oof, looks like `gatsby-source-wordpress` will only return it in HTML format, which is an interesting approach. Could be worth doing something like creating a helper function to trim the `<p>...</p>` off the excerpt string. I've updated my answer with a method for achieving this.

Comment: Yeah that's probably the solution I'm gonna go for, I haven't found anything better yet; and I'm really not sure there's a better one anyway. Thank you for your reply Michael !